# Package pgfkeys error with angles and quotes library: I do not know the key '/handlers/first char syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tikz-pic, tikz-angles

I am trying to draw a simple picture using angle and quotes libraries.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,quotes,angles,patterns}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2]
\draw [name path=xaxis] [<->] (-5,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B);
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,3) coordinate (C);
\pic [draw, ->, "$\psi$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = A--B--C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Code is generating following errors:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/handlers/first char syntax' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.38 \pgfkeys{/handlers/first char syntax=true}

 ?
```

and

`Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \pic
         [draw, ->, "$\psi$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = A--B--C};`

I understand that error is due to quotes packages. Since removing this package pgfkeys error goes away. Then I can not use \pic using angles.
I updated to Texlive 2016 but problem is still unsolved. I am using Ubunut 14.04.03. Any help?

Comment: do you have tikz v3.0 ? you can add `\pgfversion` into your document body to print the version.

Comment: It is showing 2.10. Shall I update it? If yes then how?

Comment: See this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: If you really have TL 2016, you shouldn't have Ti*k*Z 2.10. Do you have multiple TeX distributions installed? That can be problematic. Or maybe you have a stale copy of something in your TEXMFHOME?

Comment: TeX Live 2014 shipped with version 3. TeX Live 2013 may have shipped with 2.10 and been updated to 3, so that one might have 2.10. But TL 2014 on should have only 3. Moreover, whichever version you have, everything in that version should be compatible. So if it is loading a library which doesn't work with the core PGF stuff, something is wrong with your installation somewhere.

Comment: I tried with installation of TL 2016 suggested by percusse. It didnt work. Perhaps there was some dependency problem. I cleaned tex completely, reinstalled TL 2016 and texlive-base and it worked. Do not know which package was conflicting.

Comment: Probably Ti*k*Z is conflicting with itself. The idea of quotation `["$\psi$"]` is that pgfkeys has to check whether the first character is `"`. The implementation is going to be hacky. (Like the `\catcode` trick in plain-TeX.)

Comment: I had this exact problem and the reason was an old debian package named "pgf" version 2.10 that was still installed and is no longer a separate package in newer TeX Live versions. Removing that package solved the problem.